# capitalize next non-empty element in next list of nested lists

Tags: python, indexing, list-comprehension

My function aims to take a string as input then output the same string printed the number of times equal to the count of non-empty characters in the string, with the next non-empty element in the next list capitalized. The final output should contain the new strings in a list.

Example:
Input:  `hello`
Output: `["Hello", "hEllo", "heLlo", "helLo", "hellO"]`

Function:

```
def cap_wave(str):
    str_split = len([x for x in list(str) if x.isalpha()])
    len_list = [list(str) for i in range(1, str_split+1)]
    result = []
    for i in range(len(len_list)):
        temp = []
        for t in len_list[i]:
            char_modified = t
            if not char_modified:
                continue
            else:
                temp.append(char_modified)
        result.append(temp)
        new_nested = [[a.upper() if i == 0 else a for i, a in enumerate(b)] for b in result]
        nest_joins = [''.join(x) for x in new_nested]
    return nest_joins
```

The above function would fulfill all requirements except for capitalizing the next, and only the next letter, in the next string, eg `["Hello", "Hello", "Hello", "Hello", "Hello"]`. My gut says to count using index slicing, but I'm unsure how to implement without hitting index range errors.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [upper()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) to get the wanted effect if you iterate over the letters of your word:

```
text = "hello"   # this will _not_ lowercase first - do that before if you want it

k = []
for i,c in enumerate(text):
    k.append(text[:i]+ text[i].upper() + text[i+1:])

print(k)
```

Output:

```
['Hello', 'hEllo', 'heLlo', 'helLo', 'hellO']
```

[enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)  gives you your current position inside the word and you list-slice around to get the right character uppercased.

Related:

- [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: I answered with 24 seconds ahead! :D. I like the enumerate solution though!

Answer (score 1):

```
s1 = "hello"

words = []
for i in range(len(s1)):
    words.append(s1[:i] + s1[i:i+1].capitalize() + s1[i+1:])

print(words)
```

will yield

```
['Hello', 'hEllo', 'heLlo', 'helLo', 'hellO']
```